# return an image using ASP.NET Web API and display it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

### web api action :

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File
                        .ReadAllBytes(
                          HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/orderedList1.png"));
var result_ = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result_.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
result_.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
return result_;
```

[Ajax call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMjHH.png)
[image]

[respond - data in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFGhG.png)
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to make an AJAX call to this action. Just put an `<img>` tag and point its src property to your Web API endpoint:

```
<img src="api/account/GetImageByAccountId/12345" alt="" />
```

or if you don't know the `accountId` in advance, you could construct this `img` tag dynamically and inject it into the DOM using javascript:

```
var id = '12345';
$('#someDivId').prepend('<img src="api/account/GetImageByAccountId/' + id + '" alt="" />');
```

and the image will be added to a container that you need to have in your DOM:

```
<div id="someDivId"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your respond , 
there any way to that with ajax call ?
and display the the response data ?

Comment: But why would you ever want to make an AJAX call to an endpoint that returns binary garbage? That's what image tags are designed for in the HTML specification.

Comment: because i need to implement a Media Type formatter to support content negotiation of jpegs and pngs

Comment: OK, but how does this has any relation with AJAX and `<img>` tags? An `img` tag will happily display JPEGs and PNGs, as long as your server specifies the proper `Content-Type` response header.

Comment: you are right (: 
 i am new to web api , so i am doesn't really know what are the best way to display an image.

Comment: In fact it doesn't matter where the image is coming from (static file on the server, dynamic file generated by some API, ...), as long as it is a valid image, the `<img>` tag will display it by fetching it from the url provided in its `src` attribute.

Comment: This doesn't work if there's a **Authorize** attribute on the controller/action. Basically, if you try to point a **<img>>** for a Url that is intercepted by your Mvc/WebApi controller, authorization doesn't work. Any ideas to fix this? Image elements need to point to a Url like **/download/{file_id}** but I need to authorize the request. If the user is authenticated, return the file otherwise return 401 for example.